# code (php, html etc) equivalent of CTRL+F5

Tags: html, page-refresh

I am writing a personal finance project and was wondering if there was a code equivalent of the browser CTRL+F5 keypress?  I dont just want to refresh the page, I want to force a complete refresh.

As this is just a personal project, I dont really care how its achieved, or the language used.

Thanks

Ian

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force page refreshes or reloads in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803655/how-to-force-page-refreshes-or-reloads-in-jquery)

Comment: sorry, I dont know jquery very well so I didnt check that section.  I will give those answers a go.